# Insert a select while updating a field of that select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to  re-insert data in my database with just 1 field different. Is there a way for me to do that with a single query. So an insert from a updated select.

This is the select I need [image]

I need to insert this select in my database again but change the Seasoncode from 82 to 91. So I will have the data double in my database with 1 single row being different. Is there a way for me to do this with a single query?

This is the query I currently have. But I dont know how to add an update into this.

```
  INSERT INTO [OrdForm].[dbo].[SeasonDepSexGroup]
SELECT * from [SeasonDepSexGroup]
  where DepartmentCode = 'UD' and KlasseCode = 'U'
```

I tried searching for this online but coudnt find any query like this.

Comment: Please tag which DBMS you are using. You can use a `CASE` statement on your `SELECT` to manipulate the value you need to change. Also write your `INSERT` column names in order and definitely avoid using * (order isn't guaranteed).

Comment: A season sex group? Sounds lilke fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. Just select the columns you need + '91' for your season code.

```
INSERT INTO [OrdForm].[dbo].[SeasonDepSexGroup]
  (Code, Sex10Code, DepartmentCode, LastModified, SeasonCode, KlasseCode, CompanyCode, Kenmerk2)
SELECT Code, Sex10Code, DepartmentCode, LastModified, 91, KlasseCode, CompanyCode, Kenmerk2 
  FROM [SeasonDepSexGroup]
  WHERE DepartmentCode = 'UD' and KlasseCode = 'U'
```

Comment: Thank you very simple answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write clearly column name on `select`, and you can try to use `CASE WHEN` to make your expect.

```
INSERT INTO [OrdForm].[dbo].[SeasonDepSexGroup]
      (Code,Sex10Code,LastModified,SeasoneCode ....)
SELECT t.Code,
       t.Sex10Code,
       t.DepartmentCode
       t.LastModified
       (CASE WHEN t.SeasoneCode = 82 then 91 else t.SeasoneCode end) SeasoneCode 
       ...
from [SeasonDepSexGroup] t
where DepartmentCode = 'UD' and KlasseCode = 'U'
```

Answer (score 2):

@Carra and @D-Shih 's answer is great

there is anthor anwswer for you :-)

```
INSERT INTO [SeasonDepSexGroup]
  SELECT [Code], [Sexl Code], [DepartmentCode], [Last Modified], 92, [KlasseCode], [CompanyCode], [Kenmerk2] from [SeasonDepSexGroup]
  where DepartmentCode = 'UD' and KlasseCode = 'U'
  and SeasonCode = 82
  union all
  SELECT * from [SeasonDepSexGroup]
  where DepartmentCode = 'UD' and KlasseCode = 'U'
  and SeasonCode <> 82;
```

---

**Result:**

```
| Code | Sexl Code | DepartmentCode |            Last Modified | SeasonCode | KlasseCode | CompanyCode | Kenmerk2 |
|------|-----------|----------------|--------------------------|------------|------------|-------------|----------|
| TSHI |         2 |             UD |  2018-02-22T13:37:50.46Z |         82 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| ACCE |         1 |             UD |  2018-02-22T13:37:50.46Z |         82 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| ACWI |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.463Z |         82 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| BERM |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.463Z |         82 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| BODW |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.463Z |         82 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| BROE |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.467Z |         82 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
|  DAS |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.467Z |         82 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| DENI |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.467Z |         82 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| GILE |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.467Z |         82 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| HEML |         1 |             UD |  2018-02-22T13:37:50.47Z |         82 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| LEDE |         1 |             UD |  2018-02-22T13:37:50.47Z |         82 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| LING |         1 |             UD |  2018-02-22T13:37:50.47Z |         82 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| MANT |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.473Z |         82 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
|  MTO |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.473Z |         82 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| TSHI |         2 |             UD |  2018-02-22T13:37:50.46Z |         92 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| ACCE |         1 |             UD |  2018-02-22T13:37:50.46Z |         92 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| ACWI |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.463Z |         92 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| BERM |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.463Z |         92 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| BODW |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.463Z |         92 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| BROE |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.467Z |         92 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
|  DAS |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.467Z |         92 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| DENI |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.467Z |         92 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| GILE |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.467Z |         92 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| HEML |         1 |             UD |  2018-02-22T13:37:50.47Z |         92 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| LEDE |         1 |             UD |  2018-02-22T13:37:50.47Z |         92 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| LING |         1 |             UD |  2018-02-22T13:37:50.47Z |         92 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
| MANT |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.473Z |         92 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
|  MTO |         1 |             UD | 2018-02-22T13:37:50.473Z |         92 |          U |         GED |   (null) |
```

---

[db<>fiddle Test Demo Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=85fae5fe674ffaf6fce9d27e3c49b374)